# Cinnamon: power management not starting

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon

I have cinnamon installed over Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04

Within a session with cinnamon I am not able to open the power management.
If I klick on the entry within the settings menu, the window closes and nothing happens.
There is no error message.

What would be the first steps to investigate this behavior? (inspecting logs, etc.)

`ThinkPad T440S`
`Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it applying [this patch](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/5410#issuecomment-231620826) to the python code on my disk. The fix will be gone if there's an update that does not include the fix from upstream, but it's good enough for me.

To apply the patch, edit the file `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_power.py`:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_power.py
```

Find the line

```
self.up_client = UPowerGlib.Client()
```

and change it to

```
self.up_client = UPowerGlib.Client.new()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

But today, it has been completely solved.

Just upgrade `cinnamon-desktop-envirenment` with the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot and chek the "System Info".

(reset "mouse and touchpad settings")

before upgrading,my cinnamon version was "2.8.6",and now, it is "3.0.7".

so,the power management app become working.

Comment: From the ppa description "This PPA contains unofficial (though probably closest to official) builds of Cinnamon releases ..." I would like to avoid unofficial packages.